# Coordinates updating in both the rectangles- Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am displaying coordinates when the rectangle moves in the canvas.

I have multiple objects but I want to display the coordinates differently for each object.

to check this. you have to click the checkbox of rectangle then draw the rectangle using mouse events. and next shape you can draw using double click. how can I make sure the coordinates of X and Y updates only when I am moving the Rectangle created using mouse events not the Double click.

http://jsfiddle.net/HA8aP/1/

```
          mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
        mySel.y = my - offsety;

 $mouse.innerHTML = "(" + mySel.x + "," + mySel.y + ")" ;

     document.getElementById("TextROI_ULx").value=mySel.x;
        document.getElementById("TextROI_ULy").value=mySel.y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to update the coordinates for the rectangle that was drawn using mouse events, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HA8aP/2/

It adds a name parameter to Box2, and the name for the mouse drawn box will be "initialBox".  Then the name is validated when dragging.  In this example, all of the double-click created boxes are called "otherBox", but you could just as easily give them all unique names in the addRect function and then generate unique coordinate displays for each one.

```
if (mySel.name == 'initialBox') {
  $mouse.innerHTML = "(" + mySel.x + "," + mySel.y + ")";

  document.getElementById("TextROI_ULx").value = mySel.x;
  document.getElementById("TextROI_ULy").value = mySel.y;
}
```

Comment: Hi @axelstudios I have a question. If I want to update the coordinates of the double click rectangle too in a text box. I did something like this. but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/HA8aP/3/ Can you suggest where am i going wrong

Comment: I checked that creationDrag is set to true for ROI else False. I actually have 3 types of rectangles and I have to store all their coordinates separately.

Comment: Your changes were very close - it's a case sensitivity problem.  I changed `otherbox` to `otherBox`: http://jsfiddle.net/HA8aP/5/

Comment: Can I limit enabling the selection handles to increase or decrease height as in only 1 and 6 selection point should work. rest should be disable in only one case ??

Comment: Sure, just add some logic to your `switch (expectResize)` block for each case that checks whether that anchor can be moved or not.

Comment: Hi @axelstudios I tried editing it that ways but then other rectanbgles doesnt resize too. Like for eg I want to stop dragging the Layer rectangle too. I did if(isDrag.isLayer) then return ; but it doesnt work too. Please correct where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the browser will always fire both `click` and `dblclick` events for a double click.

There are many ways to differentiate between a single and double click.

The solution always goes like this:

- Suspend executing the single-click code for a small bit (200-400ms).
- Listen for additional clicks while the first click is suspended.
- If no additional click occurs, execute code for a single-click.
- If an additional click occurs, execute code for a double-click.

Here is one gist by Jacek Becela that extends jQuery to execute separate callbacks depending on whether the user single-clicked or double clicked:  https://gist.github.com/ncr/399624

Extend jQuery to differentiate between single and double clicks:

```
// Author:  Jacek Becela
// Source:  http://gist.github.com/399624
// License: MIT

jQuery.fn.single_double_click = function(single_click_callback, double_click_callback, timeout) {
  return this.each(function(){
    var clicks = 0, self = this;
    jQuery(this).click(function(event){
      clicks++;
      if (clicks == 1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(clicks == 1) {
            single_click_callback.call(self, event);
          } else {
            double_click_callback.call(self, event);
          }
          clicks = 0;
        }, timeout || 300);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
$("#yourCanvas").single_double_click(
    function(){ console.log("single-click") },
    function(){ console.log("double-click")
})
```

Comment: Hi I have a question. If I want to update the coordinates of the double click rectangle too in a text box. I did something like this. but its not working jsfiddle.net/HA8aP/3 Can you suggest where am i going wrong